# Mercurial : How to revert to a prev version after performing push

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have two branches let's say A and B. I have done few changes in A and committed my code into A then i have merged A into B and did a push.

Now the problem is i have added some unnecessary files into B.

I want o revert to a prev version of B. I have see few solutions to perform hg update -r and then forcefully push it to the repo which might lead to new heads which i don't want to do.

Bare me for the explanation, doing this for the first time. Thanks.

[I want to revert back to 3313 revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RXVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can go on your head, remove the unnecessary files, commit and push.

Go to your branch B

```
hg update -r 3316
```

Remove the files, commit and push

```
hg forget yourfilethere

hg commit -m "Remove unecessary files"

hg push
```

let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to remove or modify a pushed revision, then I am afraid Mercurial (by design) does not support this. (You can change the phase of a revision to 'draft' and strip or amend it, but when you pull again the old revision will re-appear.)

If you really need to remove the revision (e.g. it contains some huge files), then there is nothing you can do about it on your local repository; the only way this can be done is on the remote repository (e.g. having the administrator run `hg strip` directly on the remote repository, or some equivalent thereof; the BitBucket interface does support stripping a revision).

We have had a similar problem at work, where some user committed very large files to the repository, and a lot of work was done on the repository afterwards. The only way we were to solve it was using the 'convert' extension to remove the files, and then pushing into a brand new repository. (If we had just pushed the converted repository to the existing one, this would just have created duplicate revisions starting from the point where the bad files were committed.)